# How to fix blank page in Karma?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular-test

I have a blank page with Karma in my Angular project.
I just see the header with the debug button but nothing in the main container, it is totaly blank.
I should precise that I use WSL

Here is my karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Does it work with `browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],` ???

Answer (score -1):

This might be because of, there are some broken unit tests which stops the other unit tests to run. Follow the below steps and let me know:

1. Run the tests using `npm test`.
2. Open the browser and check the tests, there shouldn't be any broken or failed tests case. Check the console as well. Identify the problem and fix it.
3. Check the `gibash` or `cmd` console  where you have run the `npm test` as well. It shouldn't give any console error (Verify on console and fix it.)